# Copiar texto con python

Tags: python, pycharm

Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de copiar texto con python me explico. Estoy trabajando con indicaciones que son textos demasiado largos y a veces hay que scrollear la pantalla varias veces para poder copiarlos y quisiera saber si desde el propio python puedo copiarle y que al apretar control V se pegue lo que indique por ejemplo:

```
bienvenida = "un texto muy largo"
saludo = "hola es un gusto"
despedida = "muchas gracias por todo"
```

la estructura del codigo que tengo hasta ahora es la siguiente:

```
bienvenida = "un texto muy largo"
saludo = "hola es un gusto"
despedida = "muchas gracias por todo"
accion = ""

while accion not in ["b","s", "d"]:
    accion = input("Ingrese la primera letra de lo que quiere copiar".lower())
    if accion == "b":
        print(bienvenida)
        print("La bienvenida se ha copiado en el portapapeles")

elif accion == "s":
    print(saludo)
    print("El Saludo se ha copiado en el portapapeles")


elif accion == "d":
    print(despedida)
    print("La despedida se ha copiado en el portapapeles")
```

y que luego de eso cuando yo haga Control + V se pegue el texto de cada variable por ejemplo si selecciono "b" en el programa al hacer control V en cualquier sitio que admita texto se debe poner: un texto muy largo

muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: quieres copiar el contenido de la variable al portapapeles?

Comment: @Christian así es

Comment: Define comandos para seleccionar una palabra, una línea, un párrafo o todo el texto. Aplica la selección donde está el cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el módulo `pyperclip` para poder copiar datos al portapapeles. Por ejemplo.

```py
import pyperclip as clip

saludo = "este es un saludo"

clip.copy(saludo)
```

Al hacer `ctrl+v` se pegará el dato.

Comment: omg busque de todas las maneras posibles y solo me aparecia para copiar y pegar haciendo un nuevo archivo de texto y no en el porta papeles como este. Muchas gracias.